# Data table with legends in JfreeChart/Java

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using JFreeChart to generate images. I am trying to create barchart like below. I am able to create it successfully without data table. I tried to get more information from the jfreechar forums and found [this](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=19344) post. According to the post , its not supported by JfreeChart.

- Is it still not supported by jfreechart API ?
- If yes, can I use any other charting (open source) tool to generate chart with data table ?

Thanks

[alt text http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/4550/jfree.png](http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/4550/jfree.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a anything new in this area. One simple approach is to rely on the default `CategoryToolTipGenerator` or customize it as desired:

```
BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator(
    "({0}, {1}) = {2}", NumberFormat.getInstance()));
```

A more ambitious approach would be to add a `JTable` having a `TableModel` with access to your chart's `CategoryDataset`. A `TableCellRenderer` for the leftmost column might use the `BarRenderer`'s `getSeriesPaint()`. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834484) shows a custom renderer that implements the `Icon` interface to do the drawing.