# Is it possible to customize label for each category in bar chart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

Recently I get a requirement to create a bar chart that show data for each project. Here's an example :

[image: Example of the bar chart]

As you can see, the `Category` is the name of the project, and `Series` are different types of data in that project.

However, since system dose not guarantee the uniqueness of project name, using it as categories can cause problem, and I will not able to use project name to generate URL for different projects. On the other hand, If I use unique id as category, I won't able to display the project name. This put me into a difficult situation.

So my problem is :

Is there a way to generate customize category label on the fly in JFreeChart ?

Something similar to `CategoryItemLabelGenerator` but for category itself. So I can use unique Id as category, but display project name in chart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on how your chosen `CategoryDataset` implements the `KeyedValues2D` interface. The interface expects the keys to be unique, and the default implementation, `DefaultKeyedValues2D`, requires that the keys be `Comparable` and immutable.

Unique `String` instances are the typical concrete parameter type, but nothing in `JFreeChart` enforces the unique constraint. One approach wold be to wrap your `String` in a class that implements `Comparable` and also enforces uniqueness. The `class Value` is an [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table) that leverages the underlying `Double` implementation. Your implementation would require an additional attribute to distinguish one `project` form another, perhaps using the primary key of the source relation. You could override `toString()` to get a formatted representation of the name.

Comment: Thank you, I implement an `UniqueValue` as category, it dose solve this issue for me :)

Comment: Here is how I implement `UniqueValue` class [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10942403/554279)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I implement `UniqueValue`

```
public class UniqueValue implements Comparable<UniqueValue> {

    private final String uniqueId;
    private final String value;

    public UniqueValue(String uniqueId, String value) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(UniqueValue o) {
        return uniqueId.compareTo(o.uniqueId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return uniqueId.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj instanceof UniqueValue) {
            return uniqueId.equals(((UniqueValue)obj).uniqueId);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

You can use this class to deal with the uniqueness issue I mentioned in questions.

---

### UPDATE

However, since JFreeChart use `toString()` method to create the label for categories. So the `toString()` implementation in `UniqueValue` can be pretty weird. So here is another attempt.

First, a generator interface

```
public interface CategoryLabelGenerator {
    public String generate(Comparable<?> category);
}
```

then I make a subclass for `CategoryAxis`

```
public class CategoryLabelCustomizableCategoryAxis extends CategoryAxis {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private CategoryLabelGenerator labelGenerator;

    public CategoryLabelCustomizableCategoryAxis(String label) {
        super(label);
    }

    public void setCategoryLabelGenerator(CategoryLabelGenerator generator) {
        this.labelGenerator = generator;
    }

    @Override
    protected TextBlock createLabel(Comparable category, float width, 
        RectangleEdge edge, Graphics2D g2) {
        if (generator == null) {
            return super.createLabel(category, width, edge, g2);
        }
        return TextUtilities.createTextBlock(
            labelGenerator.generate(category),  // generate label for category on the fly
            getTickLabelFont(category), getTickLabelPaint(category), width,
            getMaximumCategoryLabelLines(), new G2TextMeasurer(g2));
    }
}
```

example :

```
JFreeChart chart = makeChart();
CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();

CategoryAxis axis = new CategoryLabelCustomizableCategoryAxis();
axis.setCategoryLabelGenerator(new MyCategoryLabelGenerator());
plot.setDomainAxis(axis);
```

This is how I customize category label. (At least for chart that use `CategoryAxis` as domain axis..)

Comment: Looks good. Is there any (useful) way to disambiguate the result of `toString()`?

Comment: (I'm not sure if I get what you mean)  Unless JFreeChart change the implementation of creating category label from `toString()` to other method, I can't come up with good one. I don't like the `toString()` looks like now either :(

Comment: Hum... Maybe I can override `createLabel` method in `CategoryAxis` class, so it won't always use `toString()` to get text of category.

Comment: Maybe a [tooltip generator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2875939/230513) for the more descriptive name?

Comment: I make another attempt, this should be the better way. See my updated answer.