# Unable to Cast the List Values into Comparable Value for JFreeChart

Tags: java, list, jfreechart

I have two classes viz. ExistInsert.java and TryExist.java . The complete code for ExistInsert is given below:

```
package tryexist;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.exist.xmldb.XQueryService;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.xmldb.api.DatabaseManager;
import org.xmldb.api.base.Collection;
import org.xmldb.api.base.Database;
import org.xmldb.api.base.Resource;
import org.xmldb.api.base.ResourceIterator;
import org.xmldb.api.base.ResourceSet;

public class ExistInsert {
    public  static String URI = "xmldb:exist://localhost:8899/exist/xmlrpc";
    public  static String driver = "org.exist.xmldb.DatabaseImpl";
    public static List mylist = new ArrayList();

    public  List insert_data(String xquery){
        try{

    Class c1 = Class.forName(driver);
    Database database=(Database) c1.newInstance();
    String collectionPath= "/db";
    DatabaseManager.registerDatabase(database);

    Collection col=DatabaseManager.getCollection(URI+collectionPath);
    XQueryService service = (XQueryService) col.getService("XQueryService","1.0");
    service.setProperty("indent", "yes");
    ResourceSet result = service.query(xquery); 
    ResourceIterator i = result.getIterator();    

    while(i.hasMoreResources()){
        Resource r =i.nextResource();
        mylist.add(((String)r.getContent()));        
    }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return mylist;
        }

    public void draw_bar(List values, List years ){
        try{
            //DefaultPieDataset data = new DefaultPieDataset();
           DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

            for(int j=0;j<values.size();j++){
                dataset.addValue();
            }
            //JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("TEST PEICHART", data, true, true, Locale.ENGLISH);

            JFreeChart chart2 = ChartFactory.createLineChart("Assets", "X","Y",dataset , PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, true);
            ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("TEST", chart2);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setSize(500, 500);

        }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here the function insert_data executes a xquery and return the result into list of String. The function draw_bar draws a barchart using the arguments viz values and years as list. The main problem I faced was converting the List into the Comparable, which is the requirement of dataset.addValue() . In my main program TryExist.java I have:

```
package tryexist;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Tryexist {      
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ExistInsert exist = new ExistInsert();
        String query = "Some query Here"
        List resp = exist.insert_data(query);
        List years = new ArrayList();
        for (int i=2060;i<=2064;i++){
            years.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(years);
        System.out.println(resp);        
        exist.draw_bar(resp,years);        
    }         
    }
```

Now executing query returns years and resp as **[2060, 2061, 2062, 2063, 2064]** and **[32905657, 3091102752, 4756935449, 7954664475, 11668355950]** respectively. Then How do I edit dataset.addValue() in ExistInsert.java so that I can pass above obtained values resp and years into draw_bar to make a bar diagram for the data passed.?

Comment: The two addValue methods [documented here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/gjdoc/org/jfree/data/category/DefaultCategoryDataset.html) don't match the signature you specified. What type of value does your List contain. Why don't you use generic, type-safe collections (`List<Integer>` instead of `List`), and why don't you respect the Java naming conventions? Why do you *want* to pass as second and third argument? i.e. what are thr rows and columns of the table?

Answer (score 2):

A complete example using [`DefaultCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/DefaultCategoryDataset.html), [`BarChartDemo1`](https://web.archive.org/web/20171028122611/http://www.jfree.org:80/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html), is included in the distribution and illustrated below. Click on the class name to see the [source code](https://web.archive.org/web/20171028121406/http://www.jfree.org:80/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html). The example uses instances of `String` as column and row keys, but any `Comparable` can by used, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930550/is-it-possible-to-customize-label-for-each-category-in-bar-chart).

[image]

Comment: Yes I had read the program and the example shows clearly that Strings are passed as the Comparable in argument of addvalue(), but when I try to parse my Year values as String, it generated error, ie i wanted to pass dataset.addValue(values[j],"Years",years[j] in String), but throws error like integer cannot be converted into string. What am I doing Wrong here?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows the problem and error you describe.

Comment: I edited the code and made more clear. Please check and suggest me.

Comment: Your example is incomplete; please read [linked article](http://sscce.org/). Also consider using `List<String>` and `Double.valueOf().

Comment: I tried using Double but failed. Error is same saying can't convert string to number or double. I have updated question including the classes i made. What am i doing wrong here?