# JTable cells not rendering shapes properly

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

I'm trying to render my JTable cells with a subclassed JPanel and the cells should appear as coloured rectangles with a circle drawn on them. When the table displays initially everything looks OK but then when a dialog or something is displayed over the cells when it is removed the cells that have been covered do not rendered properly and the circles are broken up etc. I then have to move the scroll bar or extend the window to get them to redraw properly.

The paintComponent method of the component I'm using to render the cells is below:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
    setOpaque(true);
    super.paintComponent(g); 
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    GradientPaint gradientPaint = new GradientPaint(new Point2D.Double(0, 0),    Color.WHITE, new Point2D.Double(0,
            getHeight()), paintRatingColour);
    g2d.setPaint(gradientPaint);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);  
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

    Rectangle clipBounds = g2d.getClipBounds();
    int x = new Double(clipBounds.getWidth()).intValue() - 15;
    int y = (new Double(clipBounds.getHeight()).intValue() / 2) - 6;

    if (level != null) { 
        g2d.setColor(iconColour);
        g2d.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
        g2d.fillOval(x, y, width, height); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You should give more context. For example, how is this called, what are the variables with a bigger scope (like this `level`, it seems), etc. Ideally, try to make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

As @Gnoupi observes with `level`, it's not clear how `width` and `height` are initialized. To meet a similar need, this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834484) extends `DefaultTableCellRenderer` and implements `Icon` for easier control over the geometry. It works without text as well.