# swing: creating "record" and "stop" buttons

Tags: java, swing, icons

I see that there is a [`JButton` constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) which takes an `Icon` as a parameter... but how do I get an `Icon` from a bitmap file?

Also, are there "record" and "stop" `Icon`s available from the default look and feel? or do I have to provide them myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an [ImageIcon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) from a URL, among other things (including a filename or a byte array).

You can also pass any Image into the constructor, meaning you can take full advantage of the [ImageIO](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) utility class.

Answer (score 1):

You can get icons by name from the L&F, as shown below and in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901472).

```
Icon icon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
```

You can see what's available using Rob Camick's handy [*UIManager Defaults*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/).

Addendum: Another approach is to implement the `Icon` interface and draw the icon using `Graphics2D` primitives, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834484).