# java- gui design aesthetics

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I am new to GUI design, and would like to know if there is somekind of standard "project" that I can find a set of "standard"- or not- images for my various components, e.g. buttons, jtree etc so that my GUI looks nicer. If there are icons by theme, would be great.I am using NetBeans but it seems that there is no library of icons included in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't overlook the Look & Feel icons, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711656), and there's no shortage of generously licensed [icon themes](http://art.gnome.org/themes/icon).

Comment: The gnome themes is nice. What does it mean to have a GPL for icons? There must be an "about" area in the gui that attributes the icons to the creator or something?

Comment: @user384706: Good question. On the site, most themes have a link the author's specified license (e.g. GPL or CC); for others, you have to look in the download file itself.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.javootoo.com/ for links to a bunch of different look and feel projects, some commercial.

Answer (score 2):

This code will set the GUI to look mostly like the native GUI:

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error setting native LAF: " + e);
}
```

It's not perfect since it's basically Sun trying to copy the Windows style (pre-Aero), but I like it a lot better than the default Swing style. I've never tried it on a Mac so I can't comment on the accuracy there.

Comment: The Mac version is much better when combined with Werner Randelshofer's Quaqua look and feel: http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/

Comment: On Mac, `UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()` returns `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel`, which is the default.

Comment: OTOH, maybe the OP will like the default Swing look. Full style guide with example windows at http://java.sun.com/products/jlf/ed2/book/index.html.

Comment: Updated URL for "Java Look and Feel Design Guidelines, 2nd Edition" since Oracle acquired Sun http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jlf-135985.html