# SetTitlePosition on the left of a JComponent

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to place a title on the left (or right) of a JComponent?

I don't mean justification but the real position..

I tryed setTitlePosition(TitledBorder.LEFT) on the TitledBorder associated with the JComponent but seems not to work(maybe left is for justification only?)

If it isn't possible, does anyone has a quite simple way to achieve this effect?

i would like write some code like this:

```
 TitledBorder titleB = new TitledBorder(description);
 titleB.setTitlePosition(LEFT);
```

Comment: There is no method setTitlePosition in JComponent; what is the actual component type you want to set the title on. I'm guessing TitledBorder?

Comment: @TheStijn yes thanks.. i said so to illustrate that the left position of the TitledBorder associated was relative to the JComponent. Maybe now it's more clear

Comment: Why not just put a JLabel on the same row as your component but on first column? Straightforward to do with the most common LayoutManagers: GridBagLayout, DesignGridLayout, MigLayout... Also, using TitledBorder isn't encouraged (look for Karsten Lentzsch presentations).

Comment: @jfpoilpret: yes it would be straightforward. But i am refactoring an existent project for work. TitledBorder are used to put labels over objects and everything is implemented that way. So if i can't find i workaround i have to rewrite a lot of code :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you got an `IllegalArgumentException` since LEFT is apparently not a valid position. This is the code for TitledBorder.setTitlePosition:

```
  switch (titlePosition) {
      case ABOVE_TOP:
      case TOP:
      case BELOW_TOP:
      case ABOVE_BOTTOM:
      case BOTTOM:
      case BELOW_BOTTOM:
      case DEFAULT_POSITION:
            this.titlePosition = titlePosition;
            break;
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(titlePosition +
                                    " is not a valid title position.");
    }
```

I don't think setting the title left/right of the component exists OOTB. You could however create your own border or (probably) easier your own component that has a label display the text vertically and this custom component is then added to a panel or such using BorderLayout LEFT/RIGHT.

greetz,
Stijn

Comment: no i'm not looking for a justification. I really want to put a title on the left or right side of the related JComponent.

Comment: ok, so actually you want the border to be on the left or right of the component?

Answer (score 2):

Several `JComponent` subclasses such as those for labels and buttons, include methods that set the horizontal and vertical position of the component's title text relative to its icon. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834484) shows `DefaultTableCellRenderer`, a subclass of `JLabel`, with the label on the right:

```
this.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
```

Comment: i think i haven't understood your answer. Maybe i was not clear asking the question. Now i edited it. How can i achieve something like that using titledborder?

Comment: @Overbose: Sorry, I misinterpreted the question. @TheStijn is on the right track. The [relevant tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) has more.