# Jtable1 header given to Jtable2 with properties like Sorting and Margin re-sizing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I Created two Jtable table1 and table2. I give table1 header to table2 by this code.

```
table2.setTableHeader(table1.getTableHeader());
```

but i also want to give properties of table1 header to table2. like Sorting and Margin re-sizing.

Answer (score 1):

> but i also want to give properties of table1 header to table2. like
>   Sorting and Margin re-sizing.

- to share [TableColumnModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html) for both [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)s,
- to use, override methods `columnMarginChanged` and `columnMoved`, both are implemented in [TableColumnModelListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableColumnModelListener.html),
- [e.g. simple, partial usage of, based on code by @camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11782008/714968)

Answer (score 1):

> like Sorting

Sorting is controlled by the RowSorter so I would guess you also need to share the sorter.

Read the secton from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for more information.

I guess you would use `getRowSorter(...)` on table1 and `setRowSorter(...)` on table2.

Comment: Can you explain by a little example it will be very helpfull.

Comment: and whats about Column Margin? how i will syncronize them.