# Vertical alignment of icons with various size in JRadioButtonMenuItem

Tags: swing, icons, alignment, jradiobutton

I met problem to align icons of different sizes with **JRadioButtonMenuItem**.
Here's a picture of my problem. The icons have several sizes and are left aligned.

[image: The icons have several sizes and are left aligned]

I would like to center the icons as in the picture below.

[image]

Apparently, none of the methods of JRadioButtonMenuItem class allow to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, implement the `Icon` interface using a constant enclosing size and scale the rendered content to reflect the desired image size, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833482/how-to-represent-double-values-as-circles-in-a-2d-matrix-in-java/2834484#2834484). For convenience, you can render arbitrary sized [unicode glyphs](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F300.pdf), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148336/jformattedtextfield-is-not-properly-cleared/4151403#4151403).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Calculate how much white space to add before and after an icon with the width of the widest icon and place each icon with the method setIconTextGap() such that:

```
[(widestIconWidth-iconWidth)/2_ofWhiteSpace][icon][(widestIconWidth-iconWidth)/2_ofWhiteSpace]
```

Comment: Ok, but how set the position of the icon? I don't see any method of the JRadioButton class which allows to do that? (In fact I use the JRadioButtonMenuItem class)

Comment: Because there is no method. Just create a simple method by yourself to calculate how much white space to add before and after an icon. Then use method iconTextGap

Comment: In fact the solution doesn't work. All elements are slightly shifted. It seems the layout of the radio button it's more complicated.

Comment: Yep I see now, it makes the gap between icon and text ONLY, knowing that radiobutton has both of them. An alternative showed above really works. Also there's another way around - create icons (e.g. in Photohsop) such that all of them have the same width, graphics of interest centered and background set to 100% opaque.