# Firing delay between JFrame components

Tags: java, swing, timer, jframe, delay

I want to show how merge sort perform visually using `JFrame`. What I want to do is to make visible subsequent `JLabel` with some time delay. I tried many way but all of them appears at same moment with no intermediate delay.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
       // jLabel1.setVisible(false);
        jLabel2.setVisible(false);
        jLabel3.setVisible(false);
        jLabel4.setVisible(false);
        jLabel5.setVisible(false);
        jLabel6.setVisible(false);
        jLabel7.setVisible(false);
        final Timer t=new Timer((4000), null);
         final int delay=2000;
        final ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

          jLabel1.setVisible(true);
          t.getDelay();

          jLabel2.setVisible(true);
          t.setDelay(3000);

          jLabel3.setVisible(true);
          t.setDelay(2000);

          jLabel4.setVisible(true);
          t.setDelay(2000);

          jLabel5.setVisible(true);
          t.setDelay(2000);

          jLabel6.setVisible(true);
          t.setDelay(2000);
                }
  };

  new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

But when I click button all the lables appear at same momenet though I have kept delay.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of reasons why this won't work.  Firstly, `javax.swing.Timer` doesn't work this way.  It waits in the background until the given delay has past and then calls the registered `ActionListener`s `actionPerformed` method.

Secondly, if it did work this way, it would block the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing it from processing repaint requests.

I think you will find [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) of use.

```
public class BlinkOut {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BlinkOut();
    }

    public BlinkOut() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel[] labels;
        private int[] delays;
        private Timer timer;
        private int index;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            labels = new JLabel[7];
            for (int index = 0; index < 7; index++) {
                labels[index] = new JLabel("Label " + (index + 1));
                add(labels[index]);
            }
            delays = new int[] {2000, 3000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000};
            JButton hide = new JButton("Hide");
            add(hide);
            hide.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Click");
                    index = 0;
                    labels[index].setVisible(false);
                    timer.setDelay(delays[index]);
                    timer.start();
                }
            });
            timer = new Timer(delays[0], new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Tick");
                    timer.stop();
                    index++;
                    if (index < 7) {
                        labels[index].setVisible(false);
                        timer.setDelay(delays[index]);
                        timer.start();
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the icons in the timer's action listener, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513). You can implement the `Icon` interface to render icons having a size proportional to an element's comparative value, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2834484/230513).

Addendum: *Can you please be little bit specific?*

You want to animate the intermediate steps of sorting a `List<Number>` of size `N` in some initially random order. `Number` subclasses implement `Comparable<T>`, so `compareTo()` is already done. A `GridLayout(1, 0)` of `JLabel` each having an `Icon` can be used to display the values. [`DecRenderer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2834484/230513) shows how to create icons with a proportional size; you'll want to vary the height over the interval `[0, N)`. [`GrayIcons`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513) & Mad's [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14436567/230513) show how to animate the display of the icons in some order.

Comment: I didnt get your answer, the answer you linked seems something different regarding repaint() method!Can you plz be little bit specific?