# Create GitHub punch card like plots with JFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart

I am looking for suggestions as how to create plots similar to GitHub punch cards with JFreeChart. E.g.

[image]

I guess it's some variant of a heat map, or two dimensional histogram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I found [XYBubbleRenderer](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYBubbleRenderer.html) which looks like a good starting point.

- create a `MatrixSeries` with rows = 7, columns = 24
- fill in the frequencies accordingly. I found it useful to normalise the values first to 0...1, then take the square root (smaller values have a bit better visible circles), then multiply by 0.5 (otherwise the circles are too large)
- create a `MatrixSeriesCollection` from that
- use `ChartFactory.createBubbleChart`
- the circle outline can only be removed via `plot.getRenderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(0, new Color(0, 0, 0, 0))`
- ensure integer tick units on both axis
- x-axis range -0.5 to 23.5, y-axis range -0.5 to 6.5 (or 0.5 to 7.5 if you use `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK`)
- custom `NumberTickUnit` for the y-axis to use day labels instead of numbers

The result:

[image]

Comment: And `yAxis.setInverted(true)` to have the week go from top to bottom

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `XYBubbleRenderer`, suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19357469/230513), also consider a suitable implementation of `TableCellRenderer` and `Icon`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2834484/230513).

[image]

Comment: Good point, thanks. I keep trying with JFreeChart, because I get good quality PDF, which is a bit more work with general Swing components and look-and-feel interaction.