# How to load a picture into Swing application and draw on top of it?

Tags: java, image, swing, jtable

I need to add a picture (see below) and change the colors of the cells dynamically (it will depends on a dynamic content of `JTable`).

I was thinking to load this picture as a background of a new `JTable`, however in this case it's difficult to fit `JTable`'s cells to the cells in the picture.

Another idea is to load image icons of blue colored squares into each cell of `JTable`, and then dynamically change these image icons by another ones.

So, what is a good solution for this kind of problems?

[image]

Comment: `TableCellRenderer` is intended for this.

Comment: @trashgod: So you would use TableCellRenderer in order to load image icons of blue colored squares into each cell of JTable, and then dynamically change these image icons by another ones?

Comment: No need to load a blue icon, just set the background color of your TableCellRenderer to blue.

Comment: An alternative is to draw the image on a JPanel using the paintComponent method, and draw the rectangles in the new color.

Comment: Or implement `Icon`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2834484/230513).