# How does the `Rectangle2D.Double` knows it should be displayed inside the `JOptionPane` in this call to `paintIcon()`?

Tags: java, swing, icons, paint

Suppose I've the following code for an `Icon` called `SquareIcon`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SquareIcon implements Icon
{
    private int size;
    private Color color;

    public SquareIcon(int size, Color color) {
        this.size = size;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        // Rectangle2D.Double implements Shape
        // The Double class defines a rectangle specified in double coordinates.
        Rectangle2D.Double figure = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, size, size);
        g2d.setColor(color);
        // Fills the interior of a Shape using the settings of the Graphics2D context
        g2d.fill(figure);
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconHeight() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

toghether with a corresponding test class called `SquareIconTest`:

```
public class SquareIconTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SquareIcon icon = new SquareIcon(50, Color.BLUE);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null,
                "Blue SquareIcon",
                "SquareIcon Test",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                icon
        );
    }
}
```

How does the `Rectangle2D.Double` knows it should be displayed inside the `JOptionPane` ? I see that the `x` and `y` variables must be the position inside this pane, but where do the rectangle gets the other information?

I've read the JavaDoc, and it says that `g2d.fill()` fills the interior of a `Shape`, i.e. sets its color? This doesn't provide information about the pane?

Comment: because you pass `icon` as a paramater to the `showMessageDialog` method?

Comment: the Rectangle2d.Double in your icon class does not know about where it will be displayed, the JOptionPane knows that it should be using your icon class (so this way round)

Comment: The `Graphics` context has been translated to within the context of the component been painted.

Comment: @EmersonCod, yes but the ´paintIcon()´ method doesn't return this rectangle?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen no - the paint method has `void` so it returns nothing. It gets the Graphics object to paint into. This is (shortly spoken) taken from the JOptionPane and therefore the icon appears in there

Comment: So, it is the Graphics object that tells the rectangle, that it should be displayed inside the JOptionPane? It gets this information using the fill() method?

Answer (score 2):

> The `Graphics` object tells the rectangle that it should be displayed inside the `JOptionPane`?

No. As noted in [*Painting in AWT and Swing*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), the system tells the icon to paint itself. When the `JOptionPane` is made visible, its content must be painted. Eventually, `paintComponent()` is called on the option pane label that holds the `Icon`. The geometry passed into `paintIcon()` is defined by the layout and insets of the enclosing container. In this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2834484/230513), note how `setHorizontalAlignment()` defines the relationship between the icon and text in the label. One easy way to see the chain of events is to set a break-point on the call to `fill()` and examine the call chain in a debugger. Your example adds an `Icon` directly the `JOptionPane`. As an experiment, try creating a `Label` with text/icon and adding it to the `JOptionPane`.